# how to count occurrence using tokens in c

Tags: c, windows

I found this code for converting a string into separate strings:

```
const char *s = " ,.?\n\0";

char *token;

/* get the first token */

token = strtok(buffer, s);

/* walk through other tokens */

while( token != NULL ) {

printf( " %s\n", token );
     token = strtok(NULL, s);
```

buffer containing the string.

The problem that I am having now, is that I want to count how many times a token (sub-string) occurs and print that to the user.

Can someone help?

Comment: I may have interpreted your question wrong. When you say *token (sub-string)*, do you mean that the splits have to be done after a fixed substring or after any character in your `delim` argument of `strtok`?

Comment: @pablo in my delim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done relatively simple using a structure with the token and its counter as a member, and then having a dynamic array or list or other container-like data-structure.

When you read a token, see if you already have it save, and then increase its counter. Otherwise add it with a count of one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count how many times a specific token is seen in `buffer` and the token is its own substring as returned by `strtok()`, not mixed in with some other string returned by `strtok()`

```
int main(void) {
    const char *s = " ,.?\n\0";
    char *token;
    char buffer[] = "123 456 789 456 123";
    char myToken[] = "456";
    int num = 0;

    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(buffer, s);

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(token, myToken) == 0) {
            num++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

If you want to count the occurance of every string returned by `strtok()` then you need something more complex, as described in the answer by SomeProgrammerDude, to track each string seen.